# Custom autocorrelation with overlapping sliding window

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am trying to make a custom autocorrelation function in matlab according to info in the image below:

[image]

the function works but i get an error that index exceeds matrix dimensions, mathematically it's wright but in programming am i missing something? Here is my code:

```
close all; clear all; clc;

[x,fs]=audioread('c1.wav');
N=length(x); %// length of signal
n1=128;  %// length of window
win_num=floor(N/n1); %// number of windows
m=1:n1;
for l=1:n1/2:win_num %// 50% overlapping - 64 samples for a 128 window
    for n=1:N-m 
        cmax(n)=max(sum(x(n+m)*conj(x(n))));
    end
end
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you get the error? in which line?

Comment: Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in acf_08 (line 11)
        cmax(n)=max(sum(x(n+m)*conj(x(n))));

Comment: How long is `x`? can you post a minimal working example? create a random `x` with the characteristics of the one you use so we can run the code.

Comment: x is mono signal and has length 143360 samples , even when i take the first 1000 samples it gives me the same error , so i create a new random sequence  x=randi(1000,[1,50]);
N=length(x); %length of signal
n1=25;  %length of window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that when you do `for n=1:N-m` you want to do `for n=1:N-max(m)` (or `for n=N-m(end)`).

If you do the first one `N-m` returns an array, not a single value, as `m` is an array!

Comment: yes now it works without error thanks a lot , i added n=1:N-max(m)